# Sumar total de varias filas que tienen la misma clave primaria de otra tabla

Tags: sql-server

Buen día, estimados, vengo buscando un poco de su ayuda y conocimiento referente a una consulta SQL, ya que ando dando mis primeros tanes en este lenguaje de consultas.

Les comento, tengo dos tablas que almacenan datos de facturas, en una se almacena el encabezado, es decir **ID de la factura** la **Sucursal**, **Nombre del cliente** y el **total de la facturas** etc, y en la otra tabla se almacena el detalle, es decir los productos que se facturaron, quiere decir que cada linea del detalle tiene como llave foránea el ID de la tabla factura.

Basicamente tengo que agrupar todas las facturas por sucursal, contar cuantas facturas se emitieron, cuanto suman todas ellas, sumar los detalles para que coincidan con el total que suman todas las facturas.

Agradezco, su ayuda, solamente necesito un poco de orientación al respecto, ya que he pasado varias horas tratando y nada.

Muy agradecido

Ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo hago asi mi consulta, no encuentro donde podrá estar mi error.

```
SELECT SUCURSAL,COUNT(A.ID_FACTURA),SUM(A.DOC_TOTAL),SUM(B.UNIT_PRICE)  
    FROM FACTURAS_ENCABEZADO AS A
        INNER JOIN DETALLE_FACTURAS AS B ON A.ID_FACTURA=B.ID_FACTURA
GROUP BY (A.SUCURSAL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Primero están mal los títulos de tus tablas de acuerdo a tu imagen, después estas comparando muchos valores iguales por lo que te compara todo lo que sea igual por sucursal con la tabla de `FACTURA_DETALLE` por lo que genero un subquery para dejar único `SUCURSAL` e `ID_FACTURA` y después si lo comparo por SUCURSAL y por ID_FACTURA

  SELECT a.SUCURSAL,COUNT(A.ID_FACTURA) AS ID_FACTURA,SUM(A.DOC_TOTAL) AS DOC_TOTAL,SUM(B.UNIT_PRICE) AS UNIT_PRICE 
    FROM FACTURA_ENCABEZADO AS A
            INNER JOIN (SELECT id_Factura,sucursal,sum(Unit_Price) AS Unit_Price FROM Factura_Detalle group by Id_Factura,Sucursal)  B ON A.ID_FACTURA=B.ID_FACTURA and A.Sucursal=b.Sucursal
    GROUP BY (A.SUCURSAL)
```

Comment: Perdón por lo de los títulos, solamente era para el ejemplo, algo improvisado nada mas, funcionó a la perfección tu query, y logré sacar mi reporte. te lo agradezco mucho Calderon_C